# Не получается достать значение из массива Json

Tags: java, json

Есть у меня массив в json, который выглядит примерно так:

```
contacts:[
{
"contact_id": 1
},
{
"contact_id": 2
}
]
```

Достаю я все это дело вот так:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest requestObject, HttpServletResponse responseObject) throws ServletException, IOException {
    JsonObject requestJson = getJsonContent(requestObject);
    JsonArray contactsArray=requestJson.getAsJsonArray("contacts");
```

Но никак не могу понять, как именно мне достать все значения всех переменных contact_id, чтоб по каждому из них совершить поиск в базе уже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
for (int i = 0; i < contactsArray.length(); i++) {
   JsonObject jsonObj = contactsArray.getJSONObject(i);

   //сдесь что-то делаете с определенным JsonObject
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//создаем json
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("contacts", new JSONArray()
          .put(new JSONObject().put("contacts_id", "1"))
          .put(new JSONObject().put("contacts_id", "2")));

JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("contacts");

for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(jsonObject1.getString("contacts_id"));
}
```